# win32, multiple nic, different dns per nic, how gethostbyname() behaves?

Tags: windows, networking

On a win32 multiple nic computer, how to force DNS resolving through gethostbyname() on a specific nic if all nics have different DNS configured and have the same metric ?

Otherwise, how to know which DNS will be used to resolve names each time a gethostbyname() call will be performed by the application ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. Windows will choose the DNS servers assigned to the most preferred "up" interface. However, you can change the order of interface preference. In XP (and probably 2003):

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Open Network Connections.
3. Go to the Advanced menu and choose Advanced Settings.

You will see a list of all interfaces (real or virtual) on the computer, and you can rearrange them however you wish.